# Question on partitions from combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

A partition of $n$ is said to be ‘3-phobic’ if none of the parts is a multiple of 3. Show that the number of 3-phobic partitions of $n$ is equal to the number of partitions of n that have no double-gaps.

I get what a double gap is: A partition of $n$ is said to have ‘no double-gaps’ if it is not missing two consecutive integers in the sequence $1, 2, . . . , k_{max}$ where $k_{max}$ is the size of the largest part. For example $10=5+3+2$ doesn't have a double gap but $10=5+2+2+1$ does have a double gap.

I'm really lost on how to show this.

Comment: Hint: First, argue that there are as many 3-phobic partitions of $n$ as there are partitions of $n$ having no three equal parts. (This is a particular case of Theorem 3.2.3 in Igor Pak, *Partition bijections, a survey*, http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/psurvey.pdf .) Then, argue that there are as many of the latter partitions as there are partitions of $n$ having no double-gaps. (Here, it helps to transpose the Young diagram.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you for the head start! I appreciate it